# How do i display array values in textarea?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to separate the array values with the join() but it seems not to work, it just return the last value of the array. if I use alert, it shows the values simultaneously.

```
var span_text=100;
var val= [window["tma"+kj]; //input box values from input 1 - 20 e.g. tma1, tma2,......,tma20 
if(span_text<250){
    if(val>=5 && val<=10){
         $(div3).show();// dth div shown if the condition is met
         counter1++; // number of elements in found in the condition
         var once =[window["tma"+kj].toFixed(2)];//value of the input box in an array concatinated to two deciamal places
         var kl = new Array(once);
         var alphy= kl.join(',');
         $('#com').val(alphy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `var val = window[ 'tma' + kj ];` (However, the use of global variables should be minimized.)

Comment: You are " trying to separate the array values with the join()". You must be some super good programmer.

Comment: still returns the last value like the output is 5.85, 5.65, 5.79 simultaneously in alert() but i want the output to be one (5.85, 5.65, 5.79 ) and not only the  last which is 5.79

Comment: @Aleksandar *Pih*, that's nothing. I can submit a form with alert(). `:P`

Comment: What is `window["tma"+kj]`? An array or a string? Could you post an example value of this variable?

Comment: a=parseFloat($('#tcsv18').val());  tma1 =((a-span_text)/span_text)*100; since i have tma1 to 20 im looping over using kj as the counter. 'tma'+kj would be tma1 or tma2 which hold values of input boxes

Answer (score 0):

if your array looks my following example, you can do it:

```
<textarea id="ta" rows="5" column="5"></textarea>
```

```js
var a =[1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    $('#ta').append(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var once =[window["tma"+kj].toFixed(2)];
```

You now have a one-element array containing that particular tma input.

```
var kl = new Array(once);
```

You now have a copy of that same one-element array.

So you are creating an array with only one element.  Where are the rest of the values supposed to come from?

If you want to collect the values from all the tma boxes, you could do something like this:

```
var values = []
for (var i=0; i<20; ++i) {
    values[i] = window["tma"+(i+1)].toFixed(2)
}
```

...assuming `toFixed` even returns what you want it to when called on an element in the first place.  That seems odd to me.